# swr_convert float planar to S16

Tags: c, ffmpeg, resampling, libav

How convert using libav API `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` to `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`

I'm trying to figure out how to resample and encode PCM (captured from Microphone) 44.1KHz to AAC 48.0KHz

That's my resampler initializer:

```
void initialize_resampler(SwrContext*& resamplerCtx, AVCodecContext* encoder, AVFrame*& rawResampledAudioFrame, AVStream* audioFormatStream)
{
    int nb_samples = (encoder->codec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE) ? encoder->sample_rate : encoder->frame_size;

    int encoderFrameSize = encoder->channels * av_get_bytes_per_sample(encoder->sample_fmt) * encoder->frame_size;
    rawResampledAudioFrame = allocate_audioframe(encoder->sample_fmt, encoder->channel_layout, encoder->sample_rate, nb_samples);

    // Copy the stream parameters to the muxer
    check(avcodec_parameters_from_context(audioFormatStream->codecpar, encoder));

    // Create resampler context
    resamplerCtx = swr_alloc();
    if (resamplerCtx == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not allocate resampler context");

    // Set options
    check(av_opt_set_int(resamplerCtx, "in_channel_count", 2, 0));
    check(av_opt_set_int(resamplerCtx, "in_sample_rate", 44100, 0));
    check(av_opt_set_sample_fmt(resamplerCtx, "in_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0));
    check(av_opt_set_int(resamplerCtx, "out_channel_count", encoder->channels, 0));
    check(av_opt_set_int(resamplerCtx, "out_sample_rate", encoder->sample_rate, 0));
    check(av_opt_set_sample_fmt(resamplerCtx, "out_sample_fmt", encoder->sample_fmt, 0));

    // initialize the resampling context
    check(swr_init(resamplerCtx));
}
```

And for resample I've this code:

```
    AVPacket pkt{};
    while (true)
    {
        AVPacket input_packet;
        av_init_packet(&input_packet);

        check(av_read_frame(inputContext, &input_packet));

        check(avcodec_send_packet(decoderContext, &input_packet));
        check(avcodec_receive_frame(decoderContext, decodedFrame));


        // WHAT DO HERE swr_convert(resamplerContext, )
        av_packet_unref(&input_packet);

        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        auto in_stream = inputContext->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        auto out_stream = outputContext->streams[pkt.stream_index];

        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;

        check(avcodec_send_frame(encoderContext, decodedFrame));
        check(avcodec_receive_packet(encoderContext, &pkt));

        check(av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &pkt));
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
```

REading the docs I can't figure out what exactly I  need to pass to function. I have this code to encode PCM to MP2 (output is `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`)

```
const uint8_t* inPtr[] { const_cast<const uint8_t*>(&pcmData[0]), nullptr, nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr };
uint8_t* outPtr[] { &resampledAudioData[0], nullptr, nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr };

int resampledSamplesCount{ swr_convert(
    resamplerCtx,
    outPtr,
    maxResampledSamplesCount,
    inPtr,
    inputSampleCount) };

// Negativo indica erro.
check(resampledSamplesCount);
```

pcmData is raw data from input `AVPacket` (PCM)

What I get here is: MP2 isn't planar so it uses the same outPtr[0] different from plannar which needs two valid pointers to same writable data. But what I need to pass to inPtr, for example?

When I try to use the same code, ffmpeg try to write on outPtr[1] which is nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

WHAT TO DO HERE part should be something like this:

```
int out_samples = swr_convert(swr,
                             &audio_buf,                   /* out */
                         (int)out_count,                   /* out */
             (const uint8_t**)decodedFrame->extended_data, /* in  */
                              decodedFrame->nb_samples);   /* in  */
```

As for `out_count` something like this can be used (you can improve this):

```
double frame_nb = 1.0 * encoder->sample_rate / audio_st->codec->sample_rate * decodedFrame->nb_samples;
out_count = floor(frame_nb);
```

`audio_buf` is your output buffer allocate beforehand (48000*4 is good size).
Finally now the question is how much data written the buffer. This is the formula:

```
int data_size = out_samples * av_get_bytes_per_sample(encoder->sample_fmt) * decodedFrame->channels;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer! The output buffer will be audio_buf. But how can I pass to a packet to av_interleaved_write_frame? After resample, I need to reencoder to AAC.

Comment: To get encoded data, I need to call avcodec_send_frame. So I need a frame of raw data. How can I prepare the AVFrame called resampledFrame from resampled data. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to find a generic solution to copy `audio_buf` to `AVframe::data[]` and `AVFrame::linesize[]` to set the size. It's easy for **nonplanar** PCM_S16, just use `data[0]` (allocate and memcopy from audio_buf) and set `linesize[0] = data_size` and you are good to go. Check ffmpeg doc's because I can't remember the generic functions name for this job: http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html

Comment: I will check but my destiny it's a planar buffer. In fact to a non-planar it's pretty simple. My actual program already do that. The function you said, it's av_samples_copy?

Comment: Just checked on the link, it looks like the correct function.